# Display 'Yes' in place of tick symbol and 'No' if not active in Product report

Tags: reporting

i need to display 'Yes' in place of tick symbol and 'No' for inactive product in my product report. In the screen shot below it displays "tick" symbol (i.e., default behavior of boolean fields) in Active column. Is that possible without a formula field?

[image]

Comment: Just curious as to why you are opposed to using a formula field.  It's quite simple with a formula field.

Comment: "Active" is a field of type checkbox so it will always be shown the manner as it's currently. You can't set it to display some other values. You can create some formula field to display "Yes/No" depending on this checkbox.